# How to pack a web application

Tags: security, web, pack

I'm buiding a web application (php or python). After finishing the project, i will have to transfer it to  the customer. For security reason, i want another one can't view source and database.
My Platform is Linux

Can you guess me solution ?

Comment: What you are looking for is not called "packing" but "obfuscation" and maybe some sort of compilation. By looking for those words you will find several solutions. Still, questions of "suggest me a solution" are not welcome on StackOverflow.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp sorry, my english is not so good so i express hardly :(

Answer (score 0):

The Best tool to encode your PHP code is to use

http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Or

http://www.ioncube.com/

and if you are looking for some thing basic, this is free 
http://www.phpencode.org/